# How can i change the color of the tile on which the cube steps on?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, tiles

As the title suggests, I need to change the color of the tiles as the cube moves through the level? 
It can be seen in Adventure Cube, a game by Ketchapp
This is the link for further information: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsP3FPSGUP4

Comment: Google *how to detect collison in Unity"* then *"how to change color on collision"* There is your answer.

Comment: I dont think that it will work in my case 
I have a floor which is made up of a single cube 
it has a single box collider 
I know how to detect collisions, but the collision will only return the floor game object as a whole 
Do i really need to make my floor with individual cubes in order to achieve this?

Comment: Watch the video you just linked again. Does the floor look like one cube to you? What I see is many cubes that are re-used with Object Pooling.

Comment: You are right, Its not one cube. Its an endless game. But my game isnt.
Im making a puzzle game and I haveonly one static floor per level
Im just asking that is making the floor with individual cubes the efficient solution to this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are making. Not sure how you'll detect specific "tile" collision with one cube. It is possible to use one floor but multiple colliders on the floor as a child object. This will work and is more efficient than using multiple floors and colliders

Comment: But the biggest problem will be changing the color which will require that you know and use shader programming and make sure that the floor has equal amount of faces known as tiles so that you can select a face and change it's color This is really complicated. I would go with  using cubes until you understand shader programming.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your time. In order to make it more clear I have uploaded a pic to the following link :
https://ibb.co/g0weHc
This is what Im making. The cube can walk in any direction

Comment: Use multiple tiles I mentioned about. If you want to use that one floor, you can add muliple planes on the that floor. These planes will be used to detect collision and change color and they should be made to render on top of that one floor. It's either this or use multiple cubes for tiles or use shaders like I mentioned above.

Comment: I was googling about my problem and i stumbled upon mesh creation. Is it too performance heavy to create a colored mesh right where my cube stands?